# Unable to enable two way syncing Events in Lightning for Outlook

Tags: lightning, office-365

As per Summer 17 release It is possible to sync events from salesforce to Office 365. I am able to configure sync calendar events from office 365 to salesforce.  But I am not finding any option as how i can enable syncing from salesforce to office 365.

I have configured this at Setup>Sync Configuration. Here I am getting only two options:

1. Don't Exchange
2. Exchange to salesforce

I am not able to get any option like salesforce to Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

As per Summer 16 and there is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lED1QAM) . It is still in [beta](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_sales_exchange_sync.htm) please vote that idea to get notified.

Comment: Thanks Avijit for your response but in Summer 17 release they mentioned that it is now possible to sync events from salesforce to calendar.